# Name resolution of other apps within an Internal App Service Environment

Tags: azure, dns, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Is it possible to enable apps within an internal ASE to automatically resolve the names of other apps within the ASE?

The ASE is configured to use the default domain (i.e. myase.appserviceenvironment.net) with Azure’s DNS resolution.

Reading the documentation on name resolution (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#azure-provided-name-resolution) I thought this would work out of the box. However trying this myself I’m not seeing automatic resolution. I’ve tried with FQDN, hostname, and hostname.asename all are not resolving.

The setup is an ASEv2 with a Function App talking to a regular App Service. Both are deployed on Linux using Docker images.

Answer (score 3):

Since the DNS within ILB ASE is not managed by Azure, you must deploy your own DNS to enable name resolution between apps and VMs in the ASE VNet. See [DNS configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase#dns-configuration) and [this](http://www.road4cloud.com/how-to-change-dns-server-setting-for-azure-web-app-app-service-environment/).

[image]

In this case, you might deploy a custom DNS server and change it to the DNS server of the VNet, then you will need to reboot your ASE.

Comment: Can I use Azure Public DNS as the DNS? If so, do I set that at the VNET level and the ASE will inherit those? Based on [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13943#issuecomment-416793697) we have to use an app setting on every single app service to get this working. Is that right?

Comment: Note that I’d like to keep using the default domain.

Comment: Edit my reply to remove the private DNS zone. I am afraid the DNS zone setting is mainly used for VM instances to get DNS answer in a VNet. `To resolve the records of a private DNS zone from your VNet, you must link the VNet with the zone.` so I don't think ASE will inherit those. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-overview).

Comment: If you set the DNS server settings after provisioning your PaaS environment, you have to either use an app setting on every single app service to get this working or reboot your ASE to make new DNS update, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info#customer-dns)